# Why My LinearLayout disappear?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

This is my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="testFun:"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titleTextSize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_currentStation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></View>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="tv_station:"
                android:textColor="@color/text_black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_currentStation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_home_white_r6"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/text_black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_nomal_state_arrow"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_down" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></View>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/testLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I think android system will allocate rest of the space to "testLayout", because it is the only one specify the "layout_weight" attribute, but the result is:

[image]

The "testLayout" is just disappear, why?

Comment: @userJP's answer is correct look into it. You are giving a `View` height `wrap_content` when the `View` does not have any content fix it to `1dp` or something else in `dp`..!!

Answer (score 2):

Change height of both `View` in Relative layout(use fix height in dp).

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_currentStation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"   // fix it in dp
                android:layout_weight="1"></View>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="tv_station:"
                android:textColor="@color/text_black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_currentStation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_home_white_r6"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/text_black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_nomal_state_arrow"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_down" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"   // fix it in dp
                android:layout_weight="1"></View>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: It works, but why can't I use wrap_content in View? I see that two View expand its height and take the space when I use wrap_content,but the TextView won't, why?

Comment: `wrap_content` will force any view to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For `TextView` its value is defined as text and it expand only to text's height, but `View` does not have any value, basically View is empty. So it expand to whole screen.

Comment: @ZhengChenggong Mark it as accepted, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no orientation in the testLayout, try to add a vertical or horizontal orientation to it

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="testFun:"
        android:textColor="@color/text_black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titleTextSize"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/gray" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_currentStation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></View>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="tv_station:"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_currentStation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_home_white_r6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_nomal_state_arrow"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_down" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></View>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/testLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I set the Views height to 40dp same as the TextView height and now "testLayout" is visible at the bottom

Comment: I add the android:orientation="vertical" to testLayout, but the result is the same as before, it doesn't work

Comment: As @userJP said the View doesnt have anything to wrap because it is empty so it will expand the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="testFun:"
        android:textColor="@color/text_black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titleTextSize"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/gray" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_currentStation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></View>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="tv_station:"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_currentStation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_home_white_r6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_nomal_state_arrow"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_down" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></View>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/testLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```